# Using stream of page views on a website to detect anomaly or bot-like behavior

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-test, anomaly-detection, internet, interarrival-time

I am looking at clickstream data - sequence of page visits of a user in a website. I am trying to identify anomalies in a session that could be related to bots.

To do so I am looking at a user's session and calculating the time difference between every two consecutive page impressions (views). I am calculating this time difference for all the "good-normal" users for any possible page change in the system, as a benchmark. What I see is that every time difference of every pair of pages, has a different distribution, and this is a reasonable assumption. The distribution is not normal distribution.

I would like to assess a new session - whether it follows the normal users behavior or it has an anomaly, based on the time differences I observe in the session. I had in mind to try Pearson Chi Square, but since every page change pair has a different distribution it won't work since I don't have many observations per session - I have only, let's say, 20 page impressions - meaning 19 page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to look at the user-agent in the HTTP request.  Good at catching 80-90% of bot traffic.

Look for old versions of browsers and strange things like IE6.